# Clipping two nodes with pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, path-clipping

I would like to clip two nodes containing two pictures with rounded corners.

Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit}


\node[rounded corners, inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm, anchor=north west, text width=3cm] (image_a) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}};
\node[inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm, anchor=north west, text width=3cm, below=0cm of image_a] (image_b) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}};

\clip[rounded corners]  node [inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm, draw=red, rounded corners=2mm, fit={(image_a) (image_b)}] (image) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, it does not clip properly the rounded corners:

[image]

Of course, I cannot not clip the images, because it would generate also rounded corners between the two images.

How can I crop the images in the two nodes properly at the red line?

Comment: A `\clip` needs to come before the thing that should be clipped. You can't reference future nodes that way but if you know the graphics' size beforehand you can just clip a rectangular area and place the nodes with the appropriate size and position later.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution using `clipping` options of `path picture`:

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\path [path picture={\node at (path picture bounding box.center) {\includegraphics [width=4cm]{example-image-a}};}] (0,0)[rounded corners]|- ++(1.5,2.2)-|++(1.5,-0.75)[sharp corners]|-cycle;
\path [path picture={\node at (path picture bounding box.center) {\includegraphics [width=4cm]{example-image-b}};}]  (0,0)[rounded corners]|- ++(1.5,-2.2)-|++(1.5,0.75)[sharp corners]|-cycle;
\draw [rounded corners] (0,2.2) rectangle (3,-2.2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]